# How to restore the table window in ArcMap 10.2 (stuck in maximized view)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, mac, arcgis-10.2, windows-7

I've somehow managed to maximize the table window in ArcMap 10.2 (after choosing > Open Attribute Table from the TOC).

Whenever this window opens, it's maximized, and I can't see an option to restore it so it doesn't take up the full screen - the only option is to close it.

(A possible complication is that I'm running this in Windows 7 via Bootcamp on a Mac).

Comment: I had the same problem w/the Catalog window. Double clicking the toolbar fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the same thing that happens to me now and again with 10.1. If you have a laptop and open the attribute table on an external monitor that is a different size than your laptop display it throws things out of whack when you open it when you are just on the laptop. This could also happen frequently if you use remote desktop from different computers.

If that is the case, you should be able to either connect the monitor that you were using  or remote in with a higher resolution.

If that isn't the case, another thing you can do is reset all of your settings to default (which includes window positions). To do that, rename your 'Normal.mxt' to something else and ArcGIS will create a new one next time it is started. *Unfortunately, that will also reset all of your toolbar settings and default toolboxes that are loaded as well.*

For 10.1 on Windows 7, your Normal.mxt file is located at `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.1\ArcMap\Templates`. I would expect 10.2 to be very similar although I can't speak to your Mac setup.

Comment: Bingo - deleting the normal template fixed the problem, and maximising the window re-caused it. It looks like the bug is that it's not possible to minimise the table window after maximising it. I'll log it with Esri. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- When an attribute table is maximized, you should be able to restore
  using this button in the top right:

[image: Restore button]

- Otherwise, you should be able to double click the title bar to have
  the attribute table pop into one of the docked panels.

I'm using ArcMap 10.2 on Windows 7 x64; not sure if bootcamp affects things.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately the Restore option isn't shown (only the X, weirdly) and double-clicking does nothing at all. Perhaps a Bootcamp artefact?

Comment: @StephenLead that'd be my guess. Another reason to avoid running Arc through Bootcamp if possible.